# How to create an repository and npm package in dell artifactory by jfrog

Tags: artifactory, npm-package

How can I publish Npm Package to custom JFrog artifactory using gitlab
how to create a new repository in Artifactory and then package deploy to the jfrog.

I want to create an npm package. Basically, a common code which I want to use for all of my projects. Which I created and by npm install artifactory path I have to use in my all applications.

Answer (score 2):

Using JFrog Artifactory as an NPM registry is a very common and well documented task. Follow the guidelines on [npm Publish](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/npm+Registry#npmRegistry-npmPublish(DeployingPackages)) in JFrog's official documentation.
Other related resources:

- Screencast: [Setting up an npm registry with JFrog Artifactory in less than one minute](https://jfrog.com/screencast/setting-up-an-npm-registry-with-jfrog-artifactory-in-less-than-one-minute/)
- [QuickStart Guide: npm](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/QuickStart+Guide%3A+npm)
- Knowledge base video: [How to set an npm repository in JFrog Artifactory](https://jfrog.com/knowledge-base/how-to-set-an-npm-repository-in-jfrog-artifactory-video/)